# Need hint on my calculus question.

Tags: calculus

Based on data from the U.S. Census Bureau, the chief economist of Manpower, Inc., constructed the following formula giving the percent of the total female population in the civilian labor force,P(t)  at the beginning of the tth decade (t=0  corresponds to the year 1990):
$$P(t)=\frac{74}{1+2.6e^{-0.166t+0.04536t^2-0.0066t^3}}
\quad  (0\leq t\leq11)
 $$

Assume that this trend continued for the rest of the twentieth century.
a)  What was the percent of the total female population in the civilian labor force at the beginning of 2000? 
b)  What was the growth rate of the percent of the total female population in the civilian labor forces at the beginning of 2000?

Answer:
I need some hint on how to solve this question, I tried to differentiate the function and the question ask to find the percent and growth rate at the beginning of 2000 so after differentiating do i have to substitute 2000 in place of t or not. 
I am confused with this question please anyone can help me out.

Comment: I find the $t$-th decade rather puzzling, particularly with the condition $1\le t\le 11$. In principle, $t$-th decade should mean beginning of $2000$ is $t=1$. But one cannot imagine a serious estimate to cover the next $110$ years.

Answer (score 0):

Since $t=0$ means 1990, this means $t=1$ means 2000. Thus we see that

a) What is $P(1)$

b) What is $P'(1)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Or maybe the problem statement is supposed to say that $t=0$ corresponds to the year _1890_.  That would make a lot more sense, since the "trend" is supposed to have "continued for the rest of the twentieth century", and you can't have a _continuation_ of a trend _during_ a century unless you have at least one observation during that century that is not the initial observation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem statement is actually supposed to say that $t = 0$ at the start of the year 1890 (not 1990).  In that case, $t = 1$ in 1900, $t = 2$ in 1910, and $t = 11$ in 2000.  So I think you want to evaluate $P(t)$ and its derivative at $t = 11$.

Remember that since $t$ is measured in decades, $P'(t)$ gives you the growth rate of "percent of the civilian labor force that is female" in units of percentage points per *decade*, not percentage points per year (which is how most such statistics are usually presented).